# DIV with text over an image on hover

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, image

OKay first off this is really really similiar to the http://dribbble.com homepage.

In the simplest form possible. I have an image, and i'm trying to CSS it so that when i hover over the image, a DIV shows up with some text and a partially transparent background color.

I have no idea how to do this..

Comment: Why don't you use firebug to inspect what they are doing on the dribble homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to obtain is an effect like that on Dribbble page, then you do not need to create a `div` over an `img`.

It's sufficient to have 2 versions of the image, one normal and one desaturated and with luminosity increased (or something like that, to give the impression of "transparency").

Now you create a div with the image as background and on mouseover you switch background and add the text.
On mouseout you revert the changes.

**EDIT:** Of course in practice you will dynamically assign the images name (e.g. with PHP), but that's another story. You may even automagically generate the "transparent" image by using GD libraries I guess.

A little example:

**CSS:**

```
.squareImg
    {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url("100x100.jpg"); 
    }

.squareImgOver
    {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url("100x100transp.jpg"); 
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="mydiv" class="squareImg" onmouseover="writeText();" 
    onmouseout="eraseText()"></div>
```

**JS**

```
function writeText()
    {
    var d = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    d.className = "squareImgOver";
    d.innerHTML = "something here!";
    }

function eraseText()
    {
    var d = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    d.className = "squareImg";
    d.innerHTML = "";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a start. IE6 won't do this, unless you make the parent an anchor (`a`).

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="something.jpg" alt="" />
    <div>some text</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container div {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.7; /* look into cross browser transparency */
}

.container:hover div {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: the inner div needs to be positioned OVER the image thru some means, but otherwise this is the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

@alex, I think he wants the text to appear over the image, not under it. Two ways to fix this:

1. Add `position:absolute` to the div containing the text.
2. Use a background-image instead of an img tag.

I'd go with 1, as it's better semantically and better for accessibility to use img tags for content-bearing images.

Comment: I imagined he could figure this out by himself.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using jQuery as it's easy to say "mouseover" triggers another thing to show up.

Comment: Of course, sorry I was writing my answer.

Problem is that this is not an answer, maybe a comment. Saying "use jQuery" will NOT give him any clue on how to generate that effect don't you think? It's like saying "you should use HTML and you can generate `<img>` tags!".
Provide an example and I'll be more than happy to change my vote to +1.

Comment: Ah, understood. If I had more time/inspiritation to do so I would. It looks like you have written a lengthy post on the subject, and seeing as how Dylan didn't provide ANY code what-so-ever, I'd have to create it all from scratch. Thank you for telling me, and I believe it's a valid point.