# Aligning text within a 'hover over' jquery

Tags: jquery-hover, text-alignment

I am designing a site that has images that when hovered over fade a text appears.

I have used the below thread to do this, all went well however when the text I am adding in goes to the full width and height of the image it's going over. I've tried to add padding to the text through my CSS but it doesn't work.

[DIV with text over an image on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986791/div-with-text-over-an-image-on-hover)

Here is my amended code, amended

CSS

```
    p1{font-size:1.3em;text-align:left;color:#ffffff;font-family: 'geosanslightregular';margin:100px 20px 0px 20px;padding:0;}


   div.containerdiv{position:relative}

div.texts{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; display:none; z-index:10}

div.texts:hover{display:block}
```

html

```
    <div class="grid_8">
<a href="cncpt.html">
<div class="containerdiv">
    <img src="images/cncpt.jpg" alt="background">
    <div class="texts">
<p1>LAUNCH OF E-COMMERCE MENSWEAR STORE, STOCKING EVERYONE FROM BALMAIN AND GIVENCHY TO ADIDAS X OPENING CEREMONY, YMC, NIKE AND BEYOND. BREAK HOSTED THE LAUNCH EVENT AND INTRODUCED 200+ KEY MEDIA, BRAND AND INDUSTRY CONTACTS TO THE STORE. WE CONTINUE TO OPERATE THE PRESS OFFICE FOR CNCPT AND HAVE PICKED UP FANS EVERYWHERE FROM GQ DAILY AND METRO, TO KEY ONLINE INFLUENCERS.</p1>
</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>
  <!-- end .grid_8 -->
```

Still no joy! it's showing the image fine but no text is showing over it or anywhere on the page for that matter!

Any ideas on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple answer using CSS is to use the :hover pseudo class on an anchor tag.

Set you image container as position:relative in CSS.

Create a div containing your text, formatted using html and CSS inside the image container. Position this absolute in CSS. Absolute positioning positions elements relative to the parent container positioned relative. If no element is set to position relative it will take its position from the body tag. It is important to set a width to the element too.

**THE HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <a><img src="img.jpg" alt="background">
       <div class="text">I will show on hover</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.container{position:relative;}

div.text{ position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; display:none; z-index:10;}

a:hover div.text{display:block;}
```

This will position the text over the container you set to position relative aligning to the top left corner. The z-index stacks elements one above the other. The higher the z-index the higher the element is in the stack.

[w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) have some excellent definitions and examples on all the code above if it is new to you.

The effect you are after can be achieved with html and css alone. I would advise you focus on:

1. design your site on paper
2. layout your page with html and CSS
3. add your rollover effects and jQuery animations

before adding the jQuery animation

CSS3 transitions are not compatible with all browsers, there are work arounds in CSS though a jQuery fallback is often used.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, will try it out. One thing that is standing out to me at the moment it that the text is actually placed in the jquery, I previously tried to put the text within a <div> and it stopped the hover function working. Are you suggestion I move the text out of the jquery completely?

Comment: Yes I suggest you take the text and all the elements you want to appear out of your jQuery and create a div using html and styled with CSS.

Comment: Hi there, I'm really sorry to keep bothering you with this but I have been trying to add in another <div> with little success. When I have within the html the text shows first and then disappearing on hover, so the exact opposite of that I'm after! The issue I see is within the jquery as the text has to come in within the d.innerHTML section, and as soon as I try to change this it seems to mess things up. I was wondering if you could be a bit more specific as to where I should be adding the text div and how I get it to call from the Jquery. Sorry, have got it all quite confused

Comment: dont forget to accept the answer if you found it useful, (click on the arrow to make it green)

Comment: Hey thanks for all you help so far, have amneded my code based on the CSS and HTML re-design but I'm still not seeing any text coming over the image. If you can see where I am going wrong it would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The  :hover pseudo-class works on ancor tags. Note you will have to style your a tag to remove the underline.

Comment: hey, sorry. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by an anchor tag? where should I put this and how am i calling it? sorry I can guess i am getting annoying.

Comment: take a look at www.w3schools.com or just google anchor tag. That information will help you read the code I posted above and enable you to fix problems for yourself quicker. Anchor tags should be one of the first things you learn in html.

Comment: Yea I believe I have included all the right anchor tags to my code, i've amended my original code to include my latest code which I believe from what you said should work. Can you see where I am going wrong? something to do with .text or the hover function as there is just nothing happening on roll over. Sorry to keep bugging you but any help would be really appreciated, I've gone through w3schools and I believe I've called it right above.